# Spectrum analysis

Tags: operator-theory, adjoint-operators

I have a problem:
Given the Hamiltonian $ H_n= -\frac{d|}{d^2}+V_n $ where $ V_n= a n e^{-n|x|}; a\in\Bbb R, n=1,2,....$

1)Domain in which the operators are self adjoint;

2)study and list the properties of the spectrum;

3)same as last point for $n\to \infty$

I think I know the answer to the first point: the second derivative is self adjoint in
$H^2={f\in L^2(\Bbb R)}: \int x^2\lvert f(x)\rvert^2< \infty$ and $V_n
$ is symmetric with $D(-\frac{d|}{d^2})\subset D(V_n)$ so, thanks to Kato-Rellich theorem I know $H$ is self adjoint in $H^2$.

But I'm really unsure about the other questions.

Thank you in advance.